# 550 Bad HELO - Host impersonating domain name Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I'm trying to setup Laravel auth including the 'Password Reset' function. But I am stumbeling upon a error when I try to send the email. The error I get is:

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 Bad HELO - Host impersonating domain name
```

Im using Laravel 5.6 with Cloudflare. My hosting said that that might be the issue but I've already tried to disable all Cloudflare DNS functions inside the Cloudflare Dashboard, but that didnt work. I am sure I am using the correct mails settings since they work fine on my phone and any other devices.
Also, I've tried switching ports and it doesnt matter if I fill in a valid port or not, it will keep giving me this error.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel 5.6 uses $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] as your local domain.
You should change localdomain to your MAIL_HOST

This worked for me:

config/mail.php

```
'localdomain' => env('MAIL_HOST')
```

And you should make a little change in vendor:
vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/dependency_maps/transport_deps.php

```
    //->asValue(!empty($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) && '' === preg_replace('/(?:^\[)?[a-zA-Z0-9-:\]_]+\.?/', '', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) ? trim($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], '[]') : '127.0.0.1')
    ->asValue(config('mail.localdomain'))
```

Replace commented code,

**I Know this is the worst solution but it seems that there is no other solution.**

Answer (score 1):

@bardia-mazaheri is right but better solution is to do it like this:

```php
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        // There is a bug in which the Swift library loads 'transport.localdomain' value from $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
        // which results to wrong host name for email server and causes an error:
        //   Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 Bad HELO - Host impersonating domain name
        // described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55279922/550-bad-helo-host-impersonating-domain-name-laravel
        \Swift_DependencyContainer::getInstance()
            ->register('transport.localdomain')
            ->asValue('mail.domain.com');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran against the same problem and i tried the above answer but it did not help me, but the following worked for me for strange reasons...

In your /config/mail.php add the following line:

```
'localdomain' => 'localhost'
```

don't ask me why xD